# Monitor each action a process try to make

Tags: windows-7

In windows 7 , is there any possibility to monitor a process about its activities in each point of execution?
I mean :

- Find what registry values try to read
- what files try to access
  ....etc
  Thank you !

Comment: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645

Comment: ^ Yes, I second that.

Answer (score 0):

Process Monitor v3.1

By Mark Russinovich and Bryce Cogswell

Published: March 7, 2014

[Download Process Monitor](https://download.sysinternals.com/files/ProcessMonitor.zip)
(1095 KB)

Comment: Please read [How do I recommend software](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/5329/how-do-i-recommend-software-in-my-answers/5330#5330) for some tips as to how you should go about recommending software. At the very least you should provide more than just a link, for example some additional information about the software itself (how it solves the OP's problem).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the tool called Process Monitor from Microsoft.

Process Monitor : -

Process Monitor is an advanced monitoring tool for Windows that shows real-time file system, Registry and process/thread activity. It combines the features of two legacy Sysinternals utilities, Filemon and Regmon, and adds an extensive list of enhancements including rich and non-destructive filtering, comprehensive event properties such session IDs and user names, reliable process information, full thread stacks with integrated symbol support for each operation, simultaneous logging to a file, and much more. Its uniquely powerful features will make Process Monitor a core utility in your system troubleshooting and malware hunting toolkit.

[Download Process Monitor](https://download.sysinternals.com/files/ProcessMonitor.zip)